# Vuejs handle multiple checkboxes click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have multiple parents checkboxes, each parent has childs checkboxes. When i click on parent checkbox all his childs should checked too, or unchecked.

below is my html :

```
<?php 
    // Loop over parents
    foreach($parents as $parent) 
    {
        $childs = getChilds($parent->ID);
        $chilsIDs = array_map(function($child){ return $child->ID; }, $childs)

        /*
        * - data-chlilds : list of childs ids
        */
        echo '<input 
            type="checkbox" 
            data-childs="<?php echo json_encode($childsIDs); ?>"
            @click="toggleChilds" v-model="checkAll" :value="<?php echo $parent->ID; ?>">';

        // Loop over childs
        foreach($childs as $child)
        {
            echo '<input 
            type="checkbox" 
            @click="updateCheckall" v-model="checkbox" :value="<?php echo $child->ID; ?>">';
        }
    }
?>
```

The script side :

```
new Vue({
el:'#categories-manager',
data:{
    isCheckAll:false,
    itemsData:[],
    checkbox:[],
},
methods:{
    checkAll: function(event) {
        this.isCheckAll = !this.isCheckAll;            
        this.itemsData = [];
        if(this.isCheckAll) {
            // add childs list to itemsData
            this.itemsData = JSON.parse(event.target.getAttribute('data-childs'));
            for(var key in this.itemsData) {
                // check all checkboxes
                this.checkbox.push(this.itemsData[key])
            }
        } else {
            // uncheck all checkboxes
            this.checkbox = [];
        }
    },
    updateCheckall: function(){
        if(this.itemsData.length == this.checkbox.length){
           this.isCheckAll = true;
        }else{
           this.isCheckAll = false;
        }
    }
}
```

})

**This code works ONLY for the first loop (parent/child) **, but not for others because **isCheckall** is common for all.
How i can make it working for others ? anyone has an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: How many levels are going to be there? Does the child can also have child?

Comment: hello, just one level : parent - child

Comment: You can use simple javascript as well. Create an onclick event on the parents and call a function that checks/unchecks its child.